# Using Username and Password with WinInet

Tags: c#

I am applying a proxy for my application's `WebBrowser` control using WinInet and the good thing about that method is that it doesn't affect the system's proxy and only applies the proxy to my application. However it only works with proxies that have no username and password.

Here is the code

```
private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;
private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0;
public static string ApplicationName;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, User32.WindowShowStyle nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool enabled);

[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static IntPtr InternetOpen(string lpszAgent, int dwAccessType, string lpszProxyName, string lpszProxyBypass, int dwFlags);

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static bool InternetCloseHandle(IntPtr hInternet);

[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, User32.InternetOption dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

[DllImport("wininet.dll", EntryPoint = "InternetQueryOption", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static bool InternetQueryOptionList(IntPtr handle, User32.InternetOption optionFlag, ref User32.InternetPerConnOptionList optionList, ref int size);

public static bool SetConnectionProxy(string proxyServer)
{
  IntPtr hInternet = User32.InternetOpen(User32.ApplicationName, 1, (string) null, (string) null, 0);
  User32.InternetPerConnOption[] internetPerConnOptionArray = new User32.InternetPerConnOption[2]
  {
    new User32.InternetPerConnOption()
    {
      dwOption = 1,
      Value = {
        dwValue = 2
      }
    },
    new User32.InternetPerConnOption()
    {
      dwOption = 2,
      Value = {
        pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyServer)
      }
    }
  };
  IntPtr ptr1 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOptionArray[0]) + Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOptionArray[1]));
  IntPtr ptr2 = ptr1;
  foreach (User32.InternetPerConnOption internetPerConnOption in internetPerConnOptionArray)
  {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr((object) internetPerConnOption, ptr2, false);
    ptr2 = (IntPtr) ((int) ptr2 + Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOption));
  }
  User32.InternetPerConnOptionList perConnOptionList = new User32.InternetPerConnOptionList()
  {
    pOptions = ptr1
  };
  perConnOptionList.Size = Marshal.SizeOf((object) perConnOptionList);
  perConnOptionList.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;
  perConnOptionList.OptionCount = internetPerConnOptionArray.Length;
  perConnOptionList.OptionError = 0;
  int num1 = Marshal.SizeOf((object) perConnOptionList);
  IntPtr num2 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(num1);
  Marshal.StructureToPtr((object) perConnOptionList, num2, true);
  bool flag = User32.InternetSetOption(hInternet, User32.InternetOption.InternetOptionPerConnectionOption, num2, num1);
  Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr1);
  Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(num2);
  User32.InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
  if (!flag)
    throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed!");
  else
    return true;
}

private static User32.InternetPerConnOptionList GetSystemProxy()
{
  User32.InternetPerConnOption[] internetPerConnOptionArray = new User32.InternetPerConnOption[3]
  {
    new User32.InternetPerConnOption()
    {
      dwOption = 1
    },
    new User32.InternetPerConnOption()
    {
      dwOption = 2
    },
    new User32.InternetPerConnOption()
    {
      dwOption = 3
    }
  };
  IntPtr num = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOptionArray[0]) + Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOptionArray[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOptionArray[2]));
  IntPtr ptr = num;
  foreach (User32.InternetPerConnOption internetPerConnOption in internetPerConnOptionArray)
  {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr((object) internetPerConnOption, ptr, false);
    ptr = (IntPtr) ((int) ptr + Marshal.SizeOf((object) internetPerConnOption));
  }
  User32.InternetPerConnOptionList optionList = new User32.InternetPerConnOptionList()
  {
    pOptions = num
  };
  optionList.Size = Marshal.SizeOf((object) optionList);
  optionList.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;
  optionList.OptionCount = internetPerConnOptionArray.Length;
  optionList.OptionError = 0;
  int size = Marshal.SizeOf((object) optionList);
  if (!User32.InternetQueryOptionList(IntPtr.Zero, User32.InternetOption.InternetOptionPerConnectionOption, ref optionList, ref size))
    throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed! ");
  else
    return optionList;
}

public static bool RestoreSystemProxy()
{
  IntPtr hInternet = User32.InternetOpen(User32.ApplicationName, 1, (string) null, (string) null, 0);
  User32.InternetPerConnOptionList systemProxy = User32.GetSystemProxy();
  int num1 = Marshal.SizeOf((object) systemProxy);
  IntPtr num2 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(num1);
  Marshal.StructureToPtr((object) systemProxy, num2, true);
  bool flag = User32.InternetSetOption(hInternet, User32.InternetOption.InternetOptionPerConnectionOption, num2, num1);
  Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(systemProxy.pOptions);
  Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(num2);
  if (!flag)
    throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed! ");
  User32.InternetSetOption(hInternet, User32.InternetOption.InternetOptionSettingsChanged, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
  User32.InternetSetOption(hInternet, User32.InternetOption.InternetOptionRefresh, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
  User32.InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
  return true;
}

public enum WindowShowStyle : uint
{
  Hide = 0U,
  ShowNormal = 1U,
  ShowMinimized = 2U,
  Maximize = 3U,
  ShowMaximized = 3U,
  ShowNormalNoActivate = 4U,
  Show = 5U,
  Minimize = 6U,
  ShowMinNoActivate = 7U,
  ShowNoActivate = 8U,
  Restore = 9U,
  ShowDefault = 10U,
  ForceMinimized = 11U,
}

private enum InternetOption
{
  InternetOptionRefresh = 37,
  InternetOptionSettingsChanged = 39,
  InternetOptionPerConnectionOption = 75,
}

private enum InternetOptionPerConnFlags
{
  ProxyTypeDirect = 1,
  ProxyTypeProxy = 2,
  ProxyTypeAutoProxyUrl = 4,
  ProxyTypeAutoDetect = 8,
}

private struct InternetPerConnOption
{
  public int dwOption;
  public User32.InternetPerConnOptionOptionUnion Value;
}

private struct InternetPerConnOptionList
{
  public int Size;
  public IntPtr Connection;
  public int OptionCount;
  public int OptionError;
  public IntPtr pOptions;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct InternetPerConnOptionOptionUnion
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int dwValue;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public IntPtr pszValue;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  private readonly System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftValue;
}

private enum InternetPerConnOptionEnum
{
  InternetPerConnFlags = 1,
  InternetPerConnProxyServer = 2,
  InternetPerConnProxyBypass = 3,
  InternetPerConnAutoconfigUrl = 4,
  InternetPerConnAutodiscoveryFlags = 5,
  InternetPerConnAutoconfigSecondaryUrl = 6,
  InternetPerConnAutoconfigReloadDelayMins = 7,
  InternetPerConnAutoconfigLastDetectTime = 8,
  InternetPerConnAutoconfigLastDetectUrl = 9,
  InternetPerConnFlagsUi = 10,
}
```

**Question**: How could i use that code to apply a proxy with username and password ?

**Notes**:

1. I know that there is a couple of similar questions here but i cannot
   get a good answer out of them.
2. I heard that this can be achieved using `InternetSetOption` however
   i can't find how to implement that cause i don't have enough
   knowledge about windoes functions etc...

Answer (score 0):

The proper options to set the proxy credentials in WinINET are `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME` and `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD` as shown at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You *may* need to implement [`IAuthenticate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775080.aspx) instead, since the other calls are really intended for WinINET handles, which aren't exposed when you're using the Web Browser control.

Comment: Sorry but a working code would be appreciated as i have no clue how could i implement or use IAuthenticate to get the same advantages i mentioned at the beginning of the question.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/source/browse/trunk/cEXWB.cs